# OpenIdConnectProtocolException: Message contains error: 'invalid_grant', error_description: 'The specified authorization code is no longer valid.'

Tags: authentication, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, openid-connect, openiddict

I'm having this error while login, what may be wrong?

Need to note, I've applied few minor updates to some packages on the both sides - server and client (*and before that all worked fine*):

1. "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="6.0.2" --> 6.0.3
2. "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="6.0.2" --> 6.0.3
3. "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="6.0.1" --> 6.0.3
4. "Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="6.0.2" --> 6.0.3
5. And so on for EF Core, Microsoft.Extensions, etc

---

**Stack trace:**

> System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
> ---> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectProtocolException: Message contains error: 'invalid_grant', error_description: 'The specified authorization code is no longer valid.', error_uri: 'https://documentation.openiddict.com/errors/ID2016'.
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.RedeemAuthorizationCodeAsync(OpenIdConnectMessage tokenEndpointRequest)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync()
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

---

**Auth Server logs:**

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5003
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5004
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\AuthServer
info: OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerDispatcher[0]
      The request address matched a server endpoint: Configuration.
info: OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerDispatcher[0]
      The configuration request was successfully extracted: {}.
info: OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerDispatcher[0]
      The configuration request was successfully validated.
info: OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerDispatcher[0]
      The response was successfully returned as a JSON document: {
        "issuer": "http://localhost:5004/",
        "authorization_endpoint": "http://localhost:5004/connect/authorize",
        "token_endpoint": "http://localhost:5004/connect/token",
        "introspection_endpoint": "http://localhost:5004/introspect",
        "end_session_endpoint": "http://localhost:5004/connect/logout",
        "userinfo_endpoint": "http://localhost:5004/connect/userinfo",
        "jwks_uri": "http://localhost:5004/.well-known/jwks",
        "grant_types_supported": [
          "client_credentials",
          "authorization_code",
          "refresh_token"
        ],
        "response_types_supported": [
          "code"
        ],
        "response_modes_supported": [
          "form_post",
          "fragment",
          "query"
        ],
        "scopes_supported": [
          "openid",
          "offline_access",
          "api",
          "profile"
        ],
        "claims_supported": [
          "aud",
          "exp",
          "iat",
          "iss",
          "sub"
        ],
        "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported": [
          "RS256"
        ],
        "code_challenge_methods_supported": [
          "S256"
        ],
        "subject_types_supported": [
          "public"
        ],
        "token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
          "client_secret_basic",
          "client_secret_post"
        ],
        "introspection_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
          "client_secret_basic",
          "client_secret_post"
        ],
        "claims_parameter_supported": false,
        "request_parameter_supported": false,
        "request_uri_parameter_supported": false
      }.
info: OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerDispatcher[0]
      The request address matched a server endpoint: Cryptography.
info: OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerDispatcher[0]
      The cryptography request was successfully extracted: {}.
info: OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerDispatcher[0]
      The cryptography request was successfully validated.
info: OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerDispatcher[0]
      The response was successfully returned as a JSON document: {
        "keys": [
          {
            "kid": "S_BMQOKNGJHJPWXBJUIHMDYJ4KBGJVSP13T2OAZJ",
            "use": "sig",
            "kty": "RSA",
            "alg": "RS256",
            "e": "AQAB",
            "n": "s_bmqoKNgJhJpWxbjUIhmDyj4KBgjvSP13t2OAZJv8FLVNHgkFMk8XpDetuR4EWnCOH-CfA4_QG_B-75a3ivA6eIQlHj9B1-ALe8ixxhGc_0BhaeHnRmR02P9XZPl3KfmK6zyjFUwQ84b4VHLMpAQt9lGSCmC0RWckk3ABVWKTfqNenHZyRywVfQx
MlJOrCkjVhbkXylN1NZogNsHzR1R86wCxF-6ZQAizItXnSXS0vqbeUDKK5ypvCGTixttBupes7Gl6FCc43XOjLI1yyNi4Oclla8vpAcRFT7qIlNXiAe87Cx1P2SUiCXqa28IuK5kE6GJXJ7oCuXUNT-ObJTEQ"
          }
        ]
      }.
info: OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerDispatcher[0]
      The request address matched a server endpoint: Authorization.
info: OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerDispatcher[0]
      The authorization request was successfully extracted: {
        "client_id": "dotnet",
        "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:5883/signin-oidc",
        "response_type": "code",
        "scope": "openid profile api offline_access",
        "code_challenge": "Z7awdswUZx0ETP0dpUffZ1YBvEkbHq36oyqinMHNXhM",
        "code_challenge_method": "S256",
        "response_mode": "form_post",
        "nonce": "637849932918438810.NjI1NmFkOWMtYTljYi00NDEzLWJiMDktNmY2ZTUxM2QzMzIwZGFkYjNiNDUtMDliYi00ZDVlLTk3OGUtODQ5NzlhMWRkZmJh",
        "state": "CfDJ8HK7TnNlqEtJvZnagmcXTEBxqCNdO9qAvzNhBZSsvnUV4ngLvlZ0Ft0LF2hpjjQRCB4mbP0K2_Se4z9YK_UMKuICGCwZZK3VbWxDSVemxpWMP63dNPhscDFCFFpQUbRh4bAsP5vhZMnR7K4Hg2FlUXroqwsfQTDo9KFepmZg3qlqJ8cODBDPf
v_CaY2f4QCFw-eLtGKrH1SIs4KvAcvss7OvQmqt-40OA9eU3fFG94kH50df6s48omgNb72V5hAQs6UWdBnj6DHRwnrt51a_M3NwEiOyj5dXAH6VE5Ebxd8PxHhvCkUf-9_tYTKTmbJfXiyEoNVEPLkrjtyPBTxiPxu92jm0bgqfchMSWrqAnRrQ7PzQPfxBFTJpTUMyQkHY
-w",
        "x-client-SKU": "ID_NETSTANDARD2_0",
        "x-client-ver": "6.10.0.0"
      }.
info: OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerDispatcher[0]
      The authorization request was successfully validated.
info: OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerDispatcher[0]
      The request address matched a server endpoint: Authorization.
info: OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerDispatcher[0]
      The authorization request was successfully extracted: {
        "client_id": "FMS-dotnet",
        "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:58893/signin-oidc",
        "response_type": "code",
        "scope": "openid profile api offline_access",
        "code_challenge": "Z7awdswUZx0ETP0dpUffZ1YBvEkbHq36oyqinMHNXhM",
        "code_challenge_method": "S256",
        "response_mode": "form_post",
        "nonce": "637849932918438810.NjI1NmFkOWMtYTljYi00NDEzLWJiMDktNmY2ZTUxM2QzMzIwZGFkYjNiNDUtMDliYi00ZDVlLTk3OGUtODQ5NzlhMWRkZmJh",
        "state": "CfDJ8HK7TnNlqEtJvZnagmcXTEBxqCNdO9qAvzNhBZSsvnUV4ngLvlZ0Ft0LF2hpjjQRCB4mbP0K2_Se4z9YK_UMKuICGCwZZK3VbWxDSVemxpWMP63dNPhscDFCFFpQUbRh4bAsP5vhZMnR7K4Hg2FlUXroqwsfQTDo9KFepmZg3qlqJ8cODBDPf
v_CaY2f4QCFw-eLtGKrH1SIs4KvAcvss7OvQmqt-40OA9eU3fFG94kH50df6s48omgNb72V5hAQs6UWdBnj6DHRwnrt51a_M3NwEiOyj5dXAH6VE5Ebxd8PxHhvCkUf-9_tYTKTmbJfXiyEoNVEPLkrjtyPBTxiPxu92jm0bgqfchMSWrqAnRrQ7PzQPfxBFTJpTUMyQkHY
-w",
        "x-client-SKU": "ID_NETSTANDARD2_0",
        "x-client-ver": "6.10.0.0"
      }.
info: OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerDispatcher[0]
      The authorization request was successfully validated.
info: OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerDispatcher[0]
      The authorization response was successfully returned to 'http://localhost:58893/signin-oidc' using the form post response mode: {
        "code": "[redacted]",
        "state": "CfDJ8HK7TnNlqEtJvZnagmcXTEBxqCNdO9qAvzNhBZSsvnUV4ngLvlZ0Ft0LF2hpjjQRCB4mbP0K2_Se4z9YK_UMKuICGCwZZK3VbWxDSVemxpWMP63dNPhscDFCFFpQUbRh4bAsP5vhZMnR7K4Hg2FlUXroqwsfQTDo9KFepmZg3qlqJ8cODBDPf
v_CaY2f4QCFw-eLtGKrH1SIs4KvAcvss7OvQmqt-40OA9eU3fFG94kH50df6s48omgNb72V5hAQs6UWdBnj6DHRwnrt51a_M3NwEiOyj5dXAH6VE5Ebxd8PxHhvCkUf-9_tYTKTmbJfXiyEoNVEPLkrjtyPBTxiPxu92jm0bgqfchMSWrqAnRrQ7PzQPfxBFTJpTUMyQkHY
-w"
      }.
info: OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerDispatcher[0]
      The request address matched a server endpoint: Token.
info: OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerDispatcher[0]
      The token request was successfully extracted: {
        "client_id": "dotnet",
        "client_secret": "[redacted]",
        "code": "[redacted]",
        "grant_type": "authorization_code",
        "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:5883/signin-oidc",
        "code_verifier": "ZSc9m368w1L5nAa45BKzC3u_KWfpjL_AuObTZY0l5H8"
      }.
info: OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerDispatcher[0]
      The response was successfully returned as a JSON document: {
        "error": "invalid_grant",
        "error_description": "The specified authorization code is no longer valid.",
        "error_uri": "https://documentation.openiddict.com/errors/ID2016"
      }.
```

---

Request

```
POST /signin-oidc HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5883
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 445
Origin: http://localhost:5004
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost:5004/
Cookie: .AspNetCore.OpenIdConnect.Nonce.CfDJ8HK7TnNlqEtJvZnagmcXTEC3cHpDF4OwF62WoM3Pu_IhY0BaWGPNZG8QuvCluke05nuuveAqWgrnJXltpWh950e27BF-d8kxhmEpC4cTUqKFK5ObjhVAFevKu-jHky98HWvZS6O6TV3rQM6fr0TYOh4-kNRHsODtgIRGAxuXkLvXPCA1q6bX9ryXy5huIsIUk705dWQK3f00yEMv0jpjv4aGqItksQp76OVuP3w3nasA4IJSQrYzrXKgSmi67MSABH_Ljjig1Vnxvv-TTqKmKgo=N; .AspNetCore.Correlation.Hfb7_cXI-2YLxhGXNJH44sYzNI4IpwrWy04YE5DiIDo=N; .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.PQveA42vVM8=CfDJ8HK7TnNlqEtJvZnagmcXTEAStwwI3n3s4RhrKnI85QiBaolcDshCOd8naHsLjFea04KmjAFofLehorYD3uRtBUK0wZ8ZGI3WtWZN5zKdrr5qSn2v87WWWVKQeqeE5jLANuyeIs9Dxhhy1dt0HUrb7_U; .AspNetCore.Identity.Application=CfDJ8HK7TnNlqEtJvZnagmcXTEBDcO_BcayxBKlUevk270H1lDcXKUZoVF2EqKpcWVPeYuEgGtqs_bYyL2aMpA4l5aY8JZ2nHNT4K8mXZKXrN0imVFq9LcUQ7W8n9qqZzOemR6aWeIohk4gzsM6JAnrIBBSjXjrpVPC7O3vPOyf3xZeJ8ZPuo_ksrzJpZwJN_H5YXEryz2XlROryVpy7xSi9va780_pX5A-J6G_NF8lG_dM-3iiyDkdhpN3wSIephQB5aFDma4XdUNcLdpJGxfp_LPyiy2oxJoevp9M4fEpm7E1FwQwlTr4CUkHieD22fhLSwRqzmu7d9w0g0cPxas-1t4bNC8NCugSIj0OrYnUUS8aEZXM9wJfjYIDUpW_b5k4BIvShZ6uL2Q2PezaUVngvxOwPRgCECtCDOYSmMnOtZCuF_Y55pM1nkLspRvOBXXnnnfoWTm9_lcbPAvh6AxecJ0teBLrLOkUiYPS3bkYUmrAAjlvJ4eXYHk4jhPj7l1R90lz0DqaA2mNavKFfQNFLwjAa48AdEhfl5BI-eDhapE9PDSq51Q3LYYY1xCUxEpnNiShUHLXUXqobiEKMK5vKrihSpsDe8dZCkhvBWcKihkC9w4N_cl-LCrfQi1tJQrxICsTBUE4Eo3SYCngjnm0eiLMjuEfpQOedNJRXjsw3VzlQZtIgKW1cxzTcvGfWQQTBG8nwwd4KLwonpOJOm48X6ser5rNFHGxxKt2jW0NoUR7mcL846_aHr6TE-mAkXgkvbW8Oe3DsyYwCp_MOjlwc0t6Q-zGZN58xVoR0899oc9wFHi6xouXY4LC733naAuRffohdGuCkwrZb3Gd4UKbyNxwug3GOeaj4rBod2ipKdOHtkGlp5o8jKKKS0ExWJNPBJJlau0GYJMgQ7afx9aKoMu30D68ddaQ77T3Rzbv0c3YrwokinU1CLmRJMyHmH6WLGfN3XccqEXRUgZMgl9rK95j1WC3k7-LdL2iuW382NMxmtcoR1z-zVTFTUhso2KvKS1-vM9jNeddAOc5yJ5dVFqZN-aFo5nAG4TVLvDSaCkrE8WZVaMmK67jB6r_9rsQVe5ViCcuxmBMc8F-wMY_csl-MtJpXApvjD-wCCr72clHN4aH_g7vt1AeiMNLLrVAYvMJgw5fUa7OnoEU9G4aDcAKjZ5wM90ITudtbBCxjz5WD54Hr3kF2kPOt9aXlfgCpuFeAEMsRV2vRgAtHacZQcBbijEuAefI1dK4ZNLq0fwGjZwaz6XIJqXsFfuSSrBmZy6f4GmExM2zPrH4FoiD6Os96KKgvxjfbcX4ftCIV-qd29o96WkdtigLEgxJeyU8SvM80-XMNRLhhQIQky3GR7GHjahQj_uQTNsH932SVPU64WMgBFLUs7ZEUPP6wjfpV6TnfVyaLS89YTWKYJ_QLdyLCOh8Udgz6_1ETiQP8w5CT5hJ-HPYP3tpWyL1p0ZJnyzLpkCcWH7DoP_t0Oz6_7figSdsqSQ4oIIDeAo-YyRE8zh5-Yv3_jYNZDRvGsy9SNxHvk_aIfEae9HNhprHCHPz12zQhbn8Mu2avi9QIvpQqJKuKdnozlae4BK6_g0bqx2cJWwlvo-zyxqnt7-FiBXzDos9f8gjoFyn3Hju3NH38OAZqZa4-2rXy2_RxWpHEnPfuvodDoCWF80LZ-UmvjlHUfYJ5Yus5oEaTrZer8KdKigXJvNrcU6q-hHV38hY6COInYDKV9XpKW3-1oEAEasQPIZ657OBZcgbMlgBXeaHFoxku4zhXTG0FFLKSCh-jg8uaXZuAyjdzjCPjSp8quc7i6NPSPjM-Kbz2efl5nlFIRXM-yUXu0Yesdiz4AlGLkI_Ef9RrXSWVRm3MkjAz5Q7YYWZIri_50bwnDoy4MA1KULoXwaQZ6G8GQ8THvdqHTdxxGOBHzpdpjI4smE39y9LU-76Q1UXAey6fvN9Cvm9TYWO74Pqkq0hYtFwMmjpb-8fZhvp7kSDB67HSXex7CdVEwBYdn2AMkJrsUVXmPNBqPO8IZF1lpZxW7a87dAkQIAYyIUNUaB7-SsAWjkX8KUvwQpB6A0wr4My7jU4--lORylnPtbKhkXtcjXK1wkMhgO2O_6C30X_j3mHrYpWwh7HnGG_90b_meo0VYqA6DoYuwNvnhkIlWzR-qTKYDVi-SsZEQdhNUovlxN7T7x2lIuDFuglehiKwX7ew3RVDce0UQl_B9YEVFwOeKvfBhyZxe60QEaAJdnQYoWgWaoZ4R8I7etpazjaXso-hmFOKmCmM3j4PDUzrYwNNMPRyg75DSsrex8JhORMYA9hngl48I2t33dsu_vfuzU2B-kMIHDHfzDdYQ15qEP2jjZVMqXnQRJycALHLca_jx1ZS8C659Aeu05b6t90E8OyvkNmGynt1wdw59ssdJtaHxTP7ZBGBcqYiFX0yCnkbSMeJc9D40cm-sIwNuhLz6EtN4I2x1VdMNbjPi89y6yrZLqBbGVBdUSR-UwDAFE2rCpyNbSC9r0cBst6deNtQfDEZL3VJ2EydaP5xvH8EynlSw93psFj4Y6t7AFVaRpogDr_zswrsMKWoll7rXhiueukC5j9jNzjQNZCRRLE6e3FcsPtUx4Eun4vAnKIZN4vmrqX95A5jeiOTdyjfPN1HBC88zvLBxnyrgjypmN51rVSshj-EEs4HCzXb9cKoHu2GD-bPl0E1_9dRtTIO2JIDMDoC2QUJ5-3-Sq8agPTl-vbV0v6mKDGclLeT45D3gdeFZVfOKCG9jxr4teGLzWr7Zzc76z-7TvPRoRdg40wlXGwEqBs5Q42RmJd_SjcXOWiTnbDTGGyIKz8X-qzHUCyw-wx47-qOt9VRdVlwFTkjQe1jgk27RBi_QC_QkIjC1z3KDPkAWD4hYEAGKieNtmv9_wfTfloUuA12bsIPti0XvVdhp9n3P42ZfDh9E1RKBBk-zQ2z4YnzoWJlFSQEyZ44nWHCmou6ycjHt9Fg8lsasDEaJPAPfn1X8VWd7Ve5vYz5AZQN7P0IRpU1Kj67QLT75L0uhfAid2egt74t19KafvJsXcclyeHp1zlGNm_yrj2nEZ4R6E8bbQ8DGoqlTa44Bw7a7p9SPYkggOKASVQlbj5yJNJB96OhFmE4RmvQRC0ShZna66IpBi_OS_ch-L7sroIEoZVko6Lfg_wv3B7A9Ay30Qpy3lg_sHMR9tAy8dWkKu9mZBzC78yMI3TaYtC7MtfPlTodLh--BLReHVi1XeEima4sJMzUmM5ZV0Na5zXAzjYEugu4sJckXBIQA80vrxrm6ePaopHe-OeAtC4I6AMqiLi27SQTx_5g3LiFMr50YkaG3EVrHl5IHMCfHlBjQWRbeZzkPkDa1V1BW7tN6DhPndM0s4DvzYgdmbG1JZkRn20-U2MbQxyrI25E3Lc5kZgxspGEKnu-fSwtUBvOV80PX3qSwFg-0A5w5At8IoLpyb1FF5kQn78iLQPVIr5bLmmZaTPwu9n1bc018nzzVyH8-KYaslVj8gd_lpitlDzCJSCO2Y_Tgq0Y0HGZE0JjfO10jp4SVgyxKuhAGJynWfIBuMCgk5rVpSCjHPfvn-ZTJxCbGL66WD4jZAiydvsdyUK0ssXumlEKNxR9mmNyVoe7TKdBdHDaryVjZYDaW6PUcYxxC3-0vjdv3bfH2G5hCjkdQkNDEQfsBKjAvBqOMLPLFMIT40E90opiGXuybx4d362AJytYi7NLoJdeOCNwkx5yfoAxXYr1yTmkFausY7Su2aD6pZXt1b8vUG_0s2JaqMHaWH6-68h2u-MmX_PNsc8NgbhBih-gyFr96oKAXlC3t5aIr8AvHV2OeyNTCIfkOsWdcUXbJb2rGbTRdytfpPqbMXERiuY8YHVO4ltQhFLVNxb3AzGbx2LFp2y5QRIsBJzGDcGIzfx0moTYV8KQUJmWB-gowFA6vm-rGTHcVhsmoCxDApzrSA; Identity.External=CfDJ8HK7TnNlqEtJvZnagmcXTECsSZDKEJmljUVD--xDPxD8Dn1rWkiTflCXSd91IlKyfcx0_JBBBRSRJuwxEBbcu6IxBycqtPPcJGeHrxlZAou71JKsru5sAagb1N-KrbnkMKkrMH83oRnaPv-NBywT2ONAfoC4WepLH7-AgdTT_8VU2ifNPxbwcA5lovRywrMj3WjcWINW0KwJE7nU1nB4Nw2tWdlnJ47_G5tfZBi1tchSFQu0OtkUdZLramYY7RTsDvNanSqAAgh3HpU0w2-eWJMzs6xjEipJK_azdHkqmOmRqHA3aYaWL6uGkUGBEQtAn7ohuwNpIb1DDSNJ8zAvIIjBGpW9BvJLDa_GKP0qe6Nm-aXEtIxElhW-l0ucWXkBNS80ZXMLDaPF4wjtLbXA5VymGYB5z5aQwmq4pNQe53PkXslQY8YgUW1Y6QbfAW2HazZY3snjhAHybh9JMPwTfV8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
```

Form data

```
{
    "code": "YPWe2LyqczH3B-5hySGyyvi0Ezfrc4BeIAbHABrFtH4",
    "state": "CfDJ8HK7TnNlqEtJvZnagmcXTEChyH5IIo-LXPg5s1jbtbDLg2WuabxHdPfenYYSF_1auYU3eaGZtIHqSS0tNbPHTj0OQHUvslE6ZsMts0b4RIqOk-e7vdMkP6d-tszHRW6g7ZCFfhsYVK7qCDGjKBFAmSDjJAlGHxHHr265TYiZcRY3jyhbLWBKWwmNCLXjXVlgdlIQyQlCWtY-yd9zoCEgiigdJ-suh0WJJHMqJmu20rLf3Es75aIf9EWh6Ki-0aTd6VJVamkmv6DrcPgOyOdyiplVKNVkqj8rj-qmK8RoRH0i80Qd7g03llVnoWzujKDXfUAXunGjKPAIqwSZm5MULtR1wzzxu_8fAPmKRmEnH3Su7RPWIEhBauSCLihPLA6GtQ"
}
```

Comment: The error say you are not sending calid authz code to idp back after authentication
Can you check that in your request through network?

Comment: @Sohan my server says `The authorization response was successfully returned` and after that (exact before error) `The token request was successfully extracted:{<info>}`

Comment: Could you please include the code snippet how are you sending the request to auth server? So that it can be reproduced and investigated further.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron all the stuff is going on under Openiddict's hood

Comment: I got your point, but how can the contributor help you resolve your problem if sufficient information has not been given? `Invalid grant` error has so many reasons. There might be a parameter mistaken, grant_type itself might be mistaken. So without having looked into the real snippet it's very hard to investigate. Hope I have explained the fact.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I suppose that may be related to updated packages since (as I mentioned) it worked fine before and the error says `The specified authorization code is no longer valid` (which also may point to storing data issue). Anyway, I'll try to follow your suggestion

Comment: Yes that's why asking for those additional details, if `auth code` expired then you might need to get new `code` then send that code for getting new `token` so either of the steps are stepping incorrectly.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron at the moment the authentication is failing I can observe stored values and the code is marked as valid and is not expired

Comment: Actually, its hard to predict without seeing it, its better not to through stone in bush.

Comment: Are you sening requst from postman? Or from your application code?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I do not do that programmatically, as I said, this is going on invisibly while I'm logging in via my browser. And this request data from dev panel

Comment: From browser trace its hard to say what's going wrong. Did you tried to revert the upate you have made?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron sure, when I switch to previous commit, that works. I understand, it may help if I rolled back package by package, but this is too many steps - I would like to avoid that scenario

Comment: I can understand that, but as per the current scenario reason is unknown why you are getting this error.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron thank you for your time, anyway! And happy Ramadan :)

Comment: We need to see what the request is from your server to the token endpoint, and its response. Does the auth code match what was in the post?

Comment: @Kevmeister68 didn't I posted that? btw, finally I figured out that issue is in the packages  related to EF Core somehow, I mainly suspect npgsql driver. Switching to in-memory database solves the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jeremy's great find, I finally realized what is the cause of the problem. So, it could be fixed in one line to ctor of OpenIddict DbContext:
`AppContext.SetSwitch("Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior", true);`

https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/release-notes/6.0.html#opting-out-of-the-new-timestamp-mapping-logic

Answer (score 3):

After upgrading from .NET 5 to 6, EF Core 5 to 6, and OpenIddict.EntityFrameworkCore 3.0.3 to 3.1.1 I started getting the *OpenIdConnectProtocolException: Message contains error: 'invalid_grant', error_description: 'The specified authorization code is no longer valid.'* errors.

I fixed the issue by using pgAdmin 4's Schema Diff tool to compare the old and new schemas. It generated a script like the one at the end of this answer. After applying it the error went away and authentication started working again.

[a-a-k on GitHub fixed the problem by enabling Npgsql's legacy timestamp](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/issues/1456#issuecomment-1147119324):

```cs
public AuthDbContext(DbContextOptions<AuthDbContext> options)
    : base(options)
{
    AppContext.SetSwitch("Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior", true);
}
```

The problem seems to be with the change to `timestamp with time zone`. Based on a-a-k's solution you can read that the [newer version of Npgsql EF Core assumes time zone information is available by default](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/release-notes/6.0.html?tabs=annotations#opting-out-of-the-new-timestamp-mapping-logic). That difference in schema wouldn't throw an exception from the DbContext, but it would cause these auth failures that made it seem like the code had expired when really the time zone was just shifted.

> WARNING: I recommend you use Schema Diff to generate your own migration script, and not just copy this verbatim. This is here to give you an idea of what may have changed and things you can look into.

```sql
-- This script was generated by the Schema Diff utility in pgAdmin 4. 
BEGIN;

-- Added as recommended at https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/release-notes/6.0.html#migrating-columns-from-timestamp-to-timestamptz
SET TimeZone='UTC';

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS public.delete_cascade(p_schema character varying, p_table character varying, p_key character varying, p_recursion character varying[]);

ALTER TABLE public."OpenIddictAuthorizations"
    ALTER COLUMN "CreationDate" TYPE timestamp with time zone ;
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public."OpenIddictAuthorizations" DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS "FK_OpenIddictAuthorizations_OpenIddictApplications_Application~";

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public."OpenIddictAuthorizations"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_OpenIddictAuthorizations_OpenIddictApplications_Application~" FOREIGN KEY ("ApplicationId")
    REFERENCES public."OpenIddictApplications" ("Id") MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ON DELETE NO ACTION;

ALTER TABLE public."OpenIddictTokens"
    ALTER COLUMN "CreationDate" TYPE timestamp with time zone ;

ALTER TABLE public."OpenIddictTokens"
    ALTER COLUMN "ExpirationDate" TYPE timestamp with time zone ;

ALTER TABLE public."OpenIddictTokens"
    ALTER COLUMN "RedemptionDate" TYPE timestamp with time zone ;
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public."OpenIddictTokens" DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS "FK_OpenIddictTokens_OpenIddictApplications_ApplicationId";

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public."OpenIddictTokens" DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS "FK_OpenIddictTokens_OpenIddictAuthorizations_AuthorizationId";

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public."OpenIddictTokens"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_OpenIddictTokens_OpenIddictApplications_ApplicationId" FOREIGN KEY ("ApplicationId")
    REFERENCES public."OpenIddictApplications" ("Id") MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ON DELETE NO ACTION;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public."OpenIddictTokens"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_OpenIddictTokens_OpenIddictAuthorizations_AuthorizationId" FOREIGN KEY ("AuthorizationId")
    REFERENCES public."OpenIddictAuthorizations" ("Id") MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ON DELETE NO ACTION;

END;
```

Comment: thank you, Jeremy, what a brilliant catch!